# Existence and uniqueness issue for delay differential system

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, delay-differential-equations

$\DeclareMathOperator{\sgn}{sgn}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Res}{Res}
\DeclareMathOperator{\VP}{V.P.}
\newcommand{\ph}{\varphi}
\newcommand{\inth}{\int_{-h}^0}
\newcommand{\teta}{\theta}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\<}{\leq}
\renewcommand{\>}{\geq}
\newcommand{\Int}{\int\limits}
\newcommand{\Sum}{\sum\limits}
\newcommand{\Max}{\max\limits}
\newcommand{\Sup}{\sup\limits}
\newcommand{\Lim}{\lim\limits}
\newcommand{\lmin}{\lambda_{\min}}
\newcommand{\eqdef}{\stackrel{\mathrm{def}}{=}}
\newcommand{\PC}{PC([-h,0],\R^n)}
\newcommand{\mh}{\mathfrak{h}}
\newcommand{\bh}{\mathbf h}
\newcommand{\bN}{\mathbf N}
\newcommand{\eps}{\varepsilon}
\newcommand{\dt}{\mathrm{d}t}
\newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
\newcommand{\x}{\textup{x}}
\newcommand{\y}{\textup{y}}
\newcommand{\w}{\textup{w}}$
Consider the delay differential system,
$$
\dot{x}(t)=\sum_{k=0}^m \left(A_k x(t-h_k)+\int\limits_{-h_k}^0 G_k(\theta)x(t+\theta)d\theta\right)\quad \forall t\geq t_0,\tag{1}
$$
where
\begin{gather}
t_0\geq 0,~A_k\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n},~G_k\in C\left([-h_k,0],\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}\right),~k=\overline{0,m},~n,m\in\mathbb{N},
\\
n>0,~m>0=h_0<h_1<\ldots <h_m=h.
\end{gather}
Let us denote an initial function by $\phi\in \PC$:
$$
x(t_0+\theta,\phi)=\phi(\theta)\quad\forall\theta\in[-h, 0],\tag{2}
$$
and a system state associated with a moment $t\geq 0$ as
$$
x_t(\phi):\theta\mapsto x(t+\theta,\phi)\quad\forall\theta\in[-h, 0].
$$
Consider the following norm in the space $\PC$:
$$
\lVert\phi\rVert_h=\sup\limits_{\theta\in [-h,0]}\lVert\phi(\theta)\rVert.
$$
Denote the functional $f:\PC\to\mathbb{R}^n$ as
$$
f(\phi)=\sum_{k=0}^m \left(A_k \phi(-h_k)+\int\limits_{-h_k}^0 G_k(\theta)\phi(\theta)d\theta\right).
$$
Also denote
$$
M=\sum_{k=0}^m \left(\left\lVert A_k\right\rVert + \int\limits_{-h_k}^0 \left\lVert G_k(\theta)\right\rVert d\theta\right).
$$

I wonder why the following result occurs.

**Theorem.** For any $t_0\geq 0$ and $\phi\in \PC~\exists~\tau>0$: the system $(1)$ admits a unique solution $x(t,\phi)$ of the initial value problem $(2),$ and the solution is defined on the segment $[t_0-h,t_0+\tau].$

Now I have the following proof attempt.

*Proof.* It is seen that
\begin{align}
\lVert f(\phi_1)-f(\phi_2) \rVert =& \Bigg\lVert\sum_{k=0}^m \bigg(A_k \left(\phi_1(-h_k)-\phi_2(-h_k)\right)
\\
&+\int_{-h_k}^0 G_k(\theta)\left(\phi_1(\theta)-\phi_2(\theta)\right)d\theta\bigg)\Bigg\rVert\nonumber
\\
\leq & \sum_{k=0}^m \left(\left\lVert A_k\right\rVert \lVert\phi_1-\phi_2\rVert_h + \int_{-h_k}^0 \left\lVert G_k(\theta)\right\rVert\lVert\phi_1-\phi_2\rVert_h d\theta\right)\nonumber
\\
=&M\lVert\phi_1-\phi_2\rVert_h\quad\forall \phi_1,\phi_2\in\PC.\tag{3}
\end{align}
Now select $\tau>0$ such that
$$
\tau M<1.\tag{4}
$$
Define the set
\begin{align*}
U=\left\{u:[t_0-h,t_0+\tau]\to\mathbb{R}^n,~u(t_0+\theta)=\phi(\theta)\quad\forall\theta\in[-h,0],~u\in C\left([t_0,t_0+\tau],\mathbb{R}^n\right)\right\},
\end{align*}
and $\forall u\in U$ define the operator
$$
\mathcal{A}(u)(t)=
\begin{cases}
\phi(t-t_0),\quad t\in[t_0-h,t_0],
\\
\phi(0)+\int\limits_{t_0}^t f(u_s)ds,\quad t\in[t_0,t_0+\tau],
\end{cases}
$$
with $u_s:\theta\to u(s+\theta)~\forall\theta\in [-h,0].$ Having an arbitrary $u\in U,$ let us show that $\mathcal{A}(u)\in U.$ Indeed,
\begin{align}
\theta\in[-h,0]\implies &t_0+\theta\in[t_0-h,t_0]\implies\mathcal{A}(u)(t_0+\theta)=\phi(t_0+\theta-t_0)=\phi(\theta),
\\
u\in PC\left([t_0-h,t_0+\tau],\mathbb{R}^n\right)\implies & g(s)=f(u_s)=\sum_{k=0}^m \left(A_k u(s-h_k)+\int\limits_{-h_k}^0 G_k(\theta)u(s+\theta)d\theta\right)\in PC\left([t_0,t_0+\tau],\mathbb{R}^n\right)
\\
\implies &\mathcal{A}(u)(t)=\phi(0)+\int\limits_{t_0}^t f(u_s)ds\in C\left([t_0,t_0+\tau]\right).
\end{align}
Consequently,
$$
u\in U\implies \mathcal{A}(u)\in U.\tag{5}
$$
Observe that $(4)$ implies $\forall u^1,u^2\in U$ that
\begin{align}
&\left\lVert\mathcal{A}(u^1)(t)-\mathcal{A}(u^2)(t)\right\rVert=
\begin{cases}
0,\quad t\in[t_0-h,t_0],
\\
\begin{aligned}
\left\lVert\int\limits_{t_0}^t \left(f(u_s^1)-f(u_s^2)\right)ds\right\rVert\leq &\int\limits_{t_0}^{t_0+\tau} \left\lVert f(u_s^1)-f(u_s^2)\right\rVert ds\leq M\int\limits_{t_0}^{t_0+\tau} \left\lVert u_s^1-u_s^2\right\rVert_h ds
\\
\leq &\tau M\sup\limits_{s\in [t_0-h,t_0+\tau]}\left\lVert u^1(s)-u^2(s)\right\rVert,\quad t\in[t_0,t_0+\tau],
\end{aligned}
\end{cases}
\\
&\implies \sup\limits_{s\in [t_0-h,t_0+\tau]}\left\lVert\mathcal{A}(u^1)(t)-\mathcal{A}(u^2)(t)\right\rVert\leq \tau M\sup\limits_{s\in [t_0-h,t_0+\tau]}\left\lVert u^1(s)-u^2(s)\right\rVert.\tag{6}
\end{align}
Let us show now that $U$ is closed. Assume that $\{u_n \}_{n=1}^{\infty}\subset U,~\exists\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}u_n=u_0.$ So
\begin{align}
u_n(t_0+\theta)=\phi(\theta)\quad\forall\theta\in[-h,0]\implies u_0(t_0+\theta)=\phi(\theta),
\end{align}
$C\left([t_0,t_0+\tau],\mathbb{R}^n\right)$ with sup-norm is complete subspace of the complete space of bounded real-valued functions with sup-norm
\begin{align}
\implies &C\left([t_0,t_0+\tau],\mathbb{R}^n\right)\text{ is closed}
\\
\implies & u_0\in C\left([t_0,t_0+\tau],\mathbb{R}^n\right).
\end{align}
Therefore $U$ is closed. Also $U$ is the subspace of the complete space $C\left([t_0-h,t_0+\tau],\mathbb{R}^n\right)$ with sup-norm. So $U$ is complete. Therefore $(4)$-$(6)$ and Banach Fixed-Point Theorem imply that
\begin{align}
\exists !~u^*\in U: u^*(t)=\mathcal{A}(u^*)(t)=
\begin{cases}
\phi(t-t_0),\quad t\in[t_0-h,t_0],
\\
\phi(0)+\int\limits_{t_0}^t f(u_s^*)ds,\quad t\in[t_0,t_0+\tau].
\end{cases}
\end{align}
Denote
\begin{align}
S=&\left\{s\in[t_0,t_0+\tau]:~s\text{ is discontinuity point of }g(s)=f(u_s)\right\},
\\
s_0(s)=&\left\{\begin{aligned}
\Max_{\substack{y\in S \\ y<s}}y,\quad \text{if }\exists\Max_{\substack{y\in S \\ y<s}}y,
\\t_0,\quad\text{otherwise}.
\end{aligned}\right.
\end{align}
Assume that $t\in T=\left\{s\in[t_0,t_0+\tau]:~g(s)=\Lim_{y\to s^-}g(y),~g(s_0(s))=\Lim_{y\to s_0(s)^+}g(y)\right\}.$ So $g\in C\left([s_0,t],\mathbb{R}^n\right)$ and Leibniz integral rule gives that
\begin{align}
\exists !~u^*\in U: u^*(t)=&\phi(t-t_0),\quad t\in[t_0-h,t_0],
\\
\dot{u}^*(t)=&\frac{d}{dt}\left(\phi(0)+\int\limits_{t_0}^{s_0} f(u_s^*)ds+\int\limits_{s_0}^{t} f(u_s^*)ds\right)=f(u_t^*),\quad t\in T.\tag{7}
\end{align}
It is not hard to check that any solution $x$ of $(1)$-$(2)$ belongs $U$:
\begin{align}
(2)\implies &x(t_0+\theta)=\phi(\theta)\quad\forall\theta\in[-h,0],
\\
(1)\implies &\exists\dot{x}\quad\forall t>t_0,~\exists\dot{x}_+(t_0)
\\
\implies &x\in C\left([t_0,t_0+\tau],\mathbb{R}^n\right).
\end{align}
Therefore $x\in U$ and the proof is complete if $g(s)=f(u_s)\in C\left([t_0,t_0+\tau],\mathbb{R}^n\right).$

Notice that if $(7)$ is fulfilled $\forall t\in [t_0,t_0+\tau]\setminus T$ then the proof is totally complete. But I don't know how to show it. Maybe there is another approach to the problem?

Comment: Informally, you can treat it as an ordinary differential equation but treating the past state as an input.

Comment: @copper.hat, I know how to implement this approach if $G_k=0~\forall k.$ However, if integral term appears, it is hard for me to present the system in ODE form.

Comment: @DmitryKudryakov No what copper.hat said is that you can consider that you can consider a DDE as a perturbed ODE.

Comment: @KBS Can you provide some details or a reference?

Comment: Any book on delay differential equations would show that I would say.